# He whose breath is taken

Tags: expressions

I have a character who sees something breathtaking, and I want to say that "his breath was taken by..."

Most results I get for the expression end with "away", which I don't like.

so,

1. Can I say that his breath was taken by..? is that idiomatic?
2. Can I say that he was breathtaken? I'm guessing that no, but could be nice...

Comment: Note that "adjectival" *breathtaking* is effectively an idiomatic usage. About the only other common variant is *"That took my breath away!"*. Anyone could "reverse-engineer" a past tense verb form like [*breathtaken*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was+breathtaken%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (that's about 126 written instances), but I don't think you'd find it in any dictionaries.

Comment: @FumbleFingers somehow, that small "away" turns it into a cliche.

Comment: @joeav- but it *is* cliché.  If you want to use *breathtaking* then *it took his breath away*.  If you want to use something else then that's okay too.  Maybe you could say, "It was so beautiful, he felt himself stop breathing for a moment." - something like that.

Comment: @joeav: I don't know about "somehow". It's kinda necessary to the idiomatic usage. There are over 1000 written instances of ["{What} took my breath away was {something amazing}"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22took+my+breath+away+was%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but only one (slightly florid) [instance of it without "**away**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22took+my+breath+was%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: I'm convinced. thx

Comment: So, how about "afar" or "elsewhere" or "abroad" or "astray" or "AWOL"?

Comment: @HotLicks you know... ;P

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could consider [speechless](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/speechless)?

e.g.  "He was left speechless by..."  or  "...left him speechless."

(p.s. I tried adding this as a simple comment but don't have the rep)

Comment: Another idiomatic usage that realistically you can't creatively "bend" into, for example, *He was so surprised his speech left him*.

Answer (score 1):

Why not say *X left him [breathless](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/breathless)*

> Short of breath or appearing this way because of excitement or other strong feelings:
>   *her breathless account of what happened in the courtroom*

And if you are willing to shift away from the *breath-* root, perhaps *he was [dumbstruck](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dumbstruck) by her beauty*

> So shocked or surprised as to be unable to speak:
>   *he was dumbstruck with terror*

both from *Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: it's a translation, and the original is a very nice expression, which translated literally would be "his breath was transported". That's my starting point, and I just think that "his breath was taken" could have potentially been a stronger expression

Comment: @joeav So maybe *his breath was stolen away ...*